# Mypy error when evaluating input types for numpy.reshape

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I have a python class that looks as following:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, Sequence, Literal

class TestClass():

    def test(self, a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
        return a.reshape(b, order = 'F')
```

Evaluating this module with mypy returns the error

```
No overload variant of "reshape" of "_ArrayOrScalarCommon" matches argument types "ndarray", "str"
```

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the first argument for np.reshape is an array. How do I correctly annotate this function?

Comment: Reread the `np.reshape` docs.  The method argument cannot be an array; it should be an integer or tuple.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give a shape, see [documentation for numpy.ndarray.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape)

```
class TestClass():

    def test(self, a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
        return a.reshape(b.shape, order = 'F')
```